# Windows 10/11 Built in VPN

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm having a very common problem but i'm yet to see any solutions that work on both Windows 10 and 11.  Creating a Client VPN for a Meraki appliance takes 3 steps. Creating the account in the network, Building the VPN in Windows Settings, and also setting Sec Policies in the Wan mini-port Adapter.

I have no issues with the Meraki side. But after building the VPN in Windows, i'll set the Security Protocols in the mini-port adapter.  After i do that, i'll check my VPN configurations and Username/Password is reset to General Authentication. I'll reset it back to Username/Password and then i'll recheck my adapter settings. Then those will be reset. It's an endless loop of resetting settings.

I have tried uninstalling updates (most recommended weren't found to be uninstalled), Shortcutting RASPhonebook to desktop, deleting mini-port adapters.  The closest ive been was to enter my credentials to log in, but after that, the VPN disconnects and then its back to the endless loop of constant re-configurations.

I'm not sure if anyone has found what is causing these to clash.  I have used the AnyConnect, but it caused issues on the network side of our network so i had to unisntall the feature to get our network back to function properly.

I do currently have users that have already had their VPNs created previously and have no issues. However, i have tested this out on 4 new clients and this happens on all of them.

I don't have confusion on the configurations, as i've done this many times. Just having trouble maintaining the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved a problem I have been struggling with to get windows 11 VPN support for PPTP links to work for months.

It may be related to the problem you are experiencing. It has to do with a changed microsoft made to the VPN client that broke a lot of things that worked previously

I have spent days reading everything and trying all the suggestions in dozens and dozens of posts about the problem.  Most list the same nine or ten steps, which does not enable PPTP to connect on windows 11.

I finally found the solution.  It has to do with some unexposed properties of your VPN connections.  The solution uses the microsoft group policy editor to change the local group policy on your machine so the new VPN connections you create have better defaults.

1. you will need gpedit.msc to implement the microsoft workaround detailed in
   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/dev-channel-build-25284-vpn-known-issue/11b04abe-2678-4498-905e-356b02811668   The problem was restrictions on DNS netbios negotiation caused the handshake to break; changing two defaults for the VPN connection definition allows some types of PPTP connections to succeed

if you have windows 11 home, you will need to do something more radical to get a copy of gpedit, there are several documented ways.  Majorgeeks has a script file that will unpack and configure the pieces you need from your windows installation this link will download the list of files and the script that will enable gpedit on home editions which is what I used to get access to gpedit.

https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/group_policy_editor_in_windows_10_home_edition_enabler,1.html

2. once you have made the two changes to local group policy and have rebooted your machine, I recommend you start with a clean new VPN definition as the changes to local group policy are likely a template, since the attributes are not exposed on connections you have already created you wont be able to change them on old connection objects.
3. I have been using PPTP on DD-WRT routers for years, and a few different combinations of the windows vpn settings have worked in the past, so far this is the only combination I have found that works on windows 11 clients and that is only after I made the above changes on the client machine [screenshot of VPN config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfmMc.png)

Specifically:

Type of VPN:  Point to Point
Encryption:  Require Encryption
EAP: disabled
PAP: enabled
CHAP: enabled
MSCHAPV2 enabled

There may be other combinations that work.  In the past I have let the other options negotiate and used PAP only, but those settings seem to fail solidly with windows 11 and this set of options seems to work.

I hope this helps you with your connection problems

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).